# what's the relation ship between @package and package in node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Every time when I install some package by npm , It will create two directory in node_modules : they are **/node_modules/mypackage** and **/node_modules/@mypackage**.

what's the relation ship between them?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the `@` character exists within a node_modules subfolder, that means a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) has been installed (either directly or indirectly). If you didn't install it directly, you can find out which module did via the command `npm ls @mypackage/somepackagename`, where `somepackagename` is one of the subfolders inside `node_modules/@mypackage` directory.